# Red5 live stream - huge delay on localhost

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, jwplayer, red5

I m running Red5 1.0.0 RC1, with JW Player and ffmpeg on Linux Mint14

There is a huge delay while streaming, even when everythings happening on my `machine/localhost`.

I do following steps:

1. FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -i 'http://localhost:port' rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/live.flv`
2. Red5: `TCPnoDelay` ist set to true.
3. JW Player: Bufferlength is set to 0. Also tried 2 and 3.

:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'live',
    'type': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo',
    'controlbar': 'none',
    'autostart': 'true',
    'bufferlength': '3',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '380'
  });
</script>
```

The delay is something between 7-10 seconds! 
This all is happening on and from localhost, so bandwith shouldnt be the issue.

Comment: If possible can you put something up? I would think the delay would be the amount of time it takes to connect to Red5 though.

Comment: I know, this may be not the ultimate answer to that problem, but i solved it using Wowza 3.5.0 and the VIDEO CHAT EXAMPLE! There are maybe a few milliseconds delay now. I think the problem with Red5 was on Server side, some configuration stuff. Due to lack of time, i didnt digg deeper and switched to Wowza.

Comment: Glad you got it working! :)